# Dynamic String Matching

Tags: javascript

I'm actually new in JavaScript. I'm currently work on string matching. I can understand why it is usable and so on however whenever I'm trying to make it dynamic my output is 'null' for some reason.

```
function matchString(str, match) {
    let result = str.match('/' + match + '/g');
    console.log('Output: ' + result);
}
```

matchString('Hello Stack Overflow', 'over'); // null

```
function matchString(str, match, para) {
    let result = str.match('/' + match + '/' + para);
    console.log('Output: ' + result);
}
```

matchString('Hello Stack Overflow', 'over', 'g'); // null

I want it to output 'Over' in my console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things you have to change:

- For dynamic pattern use `RegExp`
- `over` Vs `Over` is another thing. Make it case insensitive by using `i`

Here is your modified code:

```js
// With RegExp, case insensitive
function matchString1(str, match) {
    let result = str.match(new RegExp(match, 'ig'));
    console.log('Output: ' + result);
}
// With RegExp, case insensitive
function matchString2(str, match, para) {
    let result = str.match(new RegExp(match, para));
    console.log('Output: ' + result);
}
// Without RegExp, case sensitive
function matchString3(str, match) {
    let result = str.match(match);
    console.log('Output: ' + result);
}

matchString1('Hello Stack Overflow', 'over');
matchString2('Hello Stack Overflow', 'over', 'ig');
matchString3('Hello Stack Overflow', 'Over');
```

Comment: In both case it outputs 'null'

Comment: @VedatRona Please see the updated answer.